# Nginx location block not serving static file

Tags: nginx

I am trying to server data from my location block.

```
 location ~ ^/(archivefiles) {
     root /web/htdocs/archivefiles/;
  }
```

When a user visits.  `http://www.example.com/archivefiles/sports/football/1981.pdf` the page errors. I have tried the following combinations in the location block with no success.

```
root /web/htdocs/archivefiles;
root /web/htdocs/archivefiles/$1;
root /web/htdocs/$1;
```

I have looked at the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and it looks as if i am using everything correctly.

Comment: Why is this a regex?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that regex? Try a prefix one `location /archivefiles { root /web/htdocs; }`

Comment: What are you trying to Solve, for me it looks like the [X-And-Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I am deleting this question.  I was editing the incorrect nginx config file.  I am now getting a permission issue.

Comment: update the question and show us the error

Comment: @djdomi I am getting a `forbidden` error. So it is a permission issue i need to work on with the system admin